# Mapping Json Array to Java Models

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a complex json as in [here](https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cbcd5712)

I am trying to map this in my model class 'ChromeJsonModel' like :

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<ChromeJsonModel>>(){}.getType();
List<ChromeJsonModel> jsonModelList = (List<ChromeJsonModel>) new Gson().fromJson( jsonPrettyPrintString , collectionType);
```

Bu t I am receiving following error.

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

Any reason why and where am I going wrong?

Comment: In `json` everything is one (main) object because you have `{ ... }` so use `ChromeJsonModel` instead of `List<ChromeJsonModel>`.

Comment: Convert your list of object into JSON String.

Comment: @MebinJoe Do you mean like this:

ChromeJsonModel jsonModelList = new Gson().fromJson( jsonPrettyPrintString , ChromeJsonModel.class);

I tried this, but gives same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have very complex `JSON` payload where the same property could have one `JSON object` or `JSON array` of objects. `Gson` does not handle this case by default and we need to implement custom deserialiser for this kind of `one-or-many` properties. Below I created simple `POJO` model which represents your `JSON` payload:

```
class TestResponse {

    @SerializedName("test-run")
    private TestRun testRun;

    // other properties, getters, setters, toString
}

class TestRun {

    @SerializedName("test-suite")
    private List<TestSuite> testSuite;

    // other properties, getters, setters, toString
}

class TestSuite {
    private String result;
    private double duration;

    @SerializedName("test-suite")
    private List<TestSuite> testSuites;

    @SerializedName("test-case")
    private List<TestCase> testCases;

    // other properties, getters, setters, toString
}

class TestCase {

    private String fullname;

    // other properties, getters, setters, toString
}
```

As you can see `test-suite` and `test-case` are `List`-es properties. Let's implement custom deserialiser for these properties:

```
class OneOrManyJsonDeserializer<E> implements JsonDeserializer<List<E>> {

    private final Class<E> clazz;

    public OneOrManyJsonDeserializer(Class<E> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json instanceof JsonArray) {
            final JsonArray array = (JsonArray) json;
            final int size = array.size();
            if (size == 0) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            final List<E> suites = new ArrayList<>(size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                suites.add(context.deserialize(array.get(i), clazz));
            }

            return suites;
        }

        E suite = context.deserialize(json, clazz);
        return Collections.singletonList(suite);
    }
}
```

`Class<E>` is required in runtime to deserialise properly given `JSON object`. After that, let's create and customise `Gson` instance:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Type testCaseListType = new TypeToken<List<TestCase>>() {}.getType();
        Type testSuiteListType = new TypeToken<List<TestSuite>>() {}.getType();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(testCaseListType, new OneOrManyJsonDeserializer<>(TestCase.class))
                .registerTypeAdapter(testSuiteListType, new OneOrManyJsonDeserializer<>(TestSuite.class))
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        TestResponse response = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), TestResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

As, you can see, we registered two instances for each `one-to-many` types. We need to use `TypeToken` to have correct mapping of our instances.

See also:

- [Parsing JSON with GSON, object sometimes contains list sometimes
  contains object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223023/parsing-json-with-gson-object-sometimes-contains-list-sometimes-contains-object)
- [Gson uses TypeAdapter or Json Deserializer to convert data from an error list to an empty list - example with TypeAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55085592/gson-uses-typeadapter-or-json-deserializer-to-convert-data-from-an-error-list-to/55112601#55112601)

### VERSION 2

After playing with above solution I came up with below deserialiser:

```
class OneOrManyJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<?>> {

    @Override
    public List<?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final Type elementType = $Gson$Types.getCollectionElementType(typeOfT, List.class);

        if (json instanceof JsonArray) {
            final JsonArray array = (JsonArray) json;
            final int size = array.size();
            if (size == 0) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }

            final List<?> suites = new ArrayList<>(size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                suites.add(context.deserialize(array.get(i), elementType));
            }

            return suites;
        }

        Object suite = context.deserialize(json, elementType);
        return Collections.singletonList(suite);
    }
}
```

We do not need to customise it. Using `$Gson$Types` class we can get type of element and deserialise internal element. Simple usage:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new OneOrManyJsonDeserializer())
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        TestResponse response = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), TestResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Above code should also work for you.

Comment: This worked for me. Though using custom deserializer every time I have a situation like this is quite a pain. This is the only answers that attempts to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Einstein_AB, I'm glad to hear it works for you. I found out a little easier to accept solution. There is only one deserialiser we need to add this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jackson.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<ChromeJsonModel> participantJsonList = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<ChromeJsonModel>>(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `json` root element is json object:

```
{    <---- HERE YOU HAVE "OBJECT"

  "test-run": {
    "duration": 508.56199999999995,
    "result": "Passed",
    ...
   }

}
```

Change:

```
List<ChromeJsonModel> jsonModelList = (List<ChromeJsonModel>) ... ;
```

to:

```
ChromeJsonModel jsonModelList = (ChromeJsonModel) ... ;
```

You can try to generate POJO there:
http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/